# HTML feedback form hyperlink looks like it should work but doesn't

Tags: html, forms, hyperlink

just building a website for myself and really can't tell good code from bad, my apologizes for the newbage, but hey.. that's why i'm here.

Why isn't this feedback form hyperlink working? On the page it looks like a link but I can't click it, it simply won't open..

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='index_htm_files/style/jquery-ui-1.8.16.css'/>
<script src='index_htm_files/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='index_htm_files/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='index_htm_files/scripts/jquery.sim.utils.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
// <![CDATA[
$(function()
{
   $('a.sfm_feedbackform_link').click(function(){ sfm_popup_form('index_htm_files/feedbackform.php?

sfm_from_iframe=1',400,500,{title:"feedbackform"}); });
});

// ]]>
</script>
<a class='sfm_feedbackform_link' href='javascript:void(0);'>Open the feedback form</a>
```

Comment: Are there really line breaks after `feedbackform.php?`? If so, removing those line breaks would be a good start. If that's not it, then showing the source of `sfm_popup_form` and describing where it's included on the page would help too.

Comment: Thank you Chris for your insight, much appreciated, this helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have end of line characters in `JS` string. Try this:

```
$(function()
{
    $('a.sfm_feedbackform_link').click(function() {
        sfm_popup_form('index_htm_files/feedbackform.php?sfm_from_iframe=1',
            400, 500, { title: "feedbackform" });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Linek for your insight, much appreciated, this helped.

Comment: @user3756111 If it helped then you can set my answer as the correct answer so the system will know your question has been answered.